# Google Cloud Project Blocked, Abuse Detected

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

After i started my free trial of google cloud usage, just after when i tried to create a VM instance it gave the error that is written in the title. Then i created another project then i get this error for every project i create.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Normally when you get this error, it gives you an email you can contact so the relevant team can get in touch with you.

Comment: I had this about a week ago and there was an appeal form that loaded when logging in. I just described my project then they turned everything back on 2 days later. I emailed and asked what exactly had happened and they said it was a payment thing, which I didn't get because i was using free credits still!

Comment: @jamie Yeah google is a sinful company!!!

Comment: You need to setup billing with a valid funding source (e.g. credit card) in order to create GCE instances. You can have more than one project under one billing account. As such, if you billing account has issue all the projects under that billing account will be affected. With that said, we do provide billing support to all GCP customers. For future reference, you can contact billing team by filling out this form(https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_billing_internal?rd=1). I apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Answer (score 0):

The error that is communicated by the “Google Cloud Project Blocked, Abuse Detected” message, can be addressed as follows:

- By making use of the email provided for contact with the error.
- By contacting the billing team via the dedicated form: “[Google Cloud Platform Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_billing_internal?rd=1)”. In case your account has been already suspended, you can submit supporting documents via the “[Submit verification documents to reopen your account](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/verify?visit_id=1-636223431579502321-2663669866&source=wallet_to_pmts_form_rd&rd=2)” page, as needed.

Each one of the above options will lead you to the billing support team. They are ready to help all GCP customers, and able to verify your funding source, confirm its validity, and reinstate normal access to your projects.

If you have multiple projects covered by a unique billing account, any problems with this one account, including blocking, would reflect on all existing projects, and also on eventual future projects opened under the same account.