# Unable to send google container registry in docker image

Tags: serverless, docker-image, google-container-registry

I'm trying to send my first image to gcr(google container reg.) via local bash, but somehow I couldn't do it even though I added my current user as 'owner' to the project. In the last link that gave me an error, the following was written.

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"Unauthorized access."}]}
```

Also, my ubuntu distribution ip that I use on wsl2 was  banned by google on the grounds that I tried too much. This is my 2nd problem that I need to solve.

I encountered my problem in the first item through powershell on my local computer.
What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The refusal to connect to GCP might be related to the IP ban that you mentioned, was there any specified length to the ban? [Usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116399/), an email is sent with more details about the ban. Otherwise, there is specific [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) dealing with authenticating to Container Registry. The documentation lists several authentication methods:

- gcloud credential helper
- Standalone credential helper
- Access token
- JSON key file

Which of these methods are you having issues with? The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) lists the procedure to authenticate properly with each of these methods. Is the correct account configured? It could be a different account or a service account is being used instead.